Finding a constant to bound a function
I'm working on the following problem:

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)\ge 0$ and $f(0)\ne 0$. Let $g$ be a function defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)\mathrm{d}x<\infty$. Suppose
$$f(x)\le f(0)+M\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)^{p-1}f(y)g(y)\mathrm{d}y,$$
where $M>0$ is a constant and $0<p<1$, prove (or disprove) that there exists a constant $K\ne 0$ such that $f(x)\le Kf(0)$.

I attempt to do this via Gronwall's inequality, but I failed since the integral may "blow up" near $0$. Here is my attempt:

To use $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)\mathrm{d}x<\infty$, apply Holder's inequality to obtain
$$
f\left( x \right) \le f\left( 0 \right) +M\left( \int_0^x{\left( x-y \right) ^{qp-q}\mathrm{d}y} \right) ^{\frac{1}{q}}\left( \int_0^x{f^{q^*}\left( y \right) g^{q^*}\left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y} \right) ^{\frac{1}{q^*}},
$$
therefore
$$
\begin{align}
f^{q^*}\left( x \right) &\le f^{q^*}\left( 0 \right) +M^{q^*}\left( \int_0^x{\left( x-y \right) ^{qp-q}\mathrm{d}y} \right) ^{\frac{q^*}{q}}\int_0^x{f^{q^*}\left( y \right) g^{q^*}\left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y}
\\
&\le f^{q^*}\left( 0 \right) \exp \left\{ M^{q^*}\left( \int_0^x{\left( x-y \right) ^{qp-q}\mathrm{d}y} \right) ^{\frac{q^*}{q}}\int_0^x{g^{q^*}\left( y \right) \mathrm{d}y} \right\} ,
\end{align}
$$
but I cannot go further.

Indeed, I doubt whether the result is true. However my purpose is to "improve" a result. See the following:

The best condition that $g$ must satisfy to obtain such $K$ that I have gotten is $\int_0^{\infty}{e^{2x}g^2\left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x}$. The prove of which is easy, just multiply $e^{x}e^{-x}$ in the integrand and use Cauchy's and Gronwall's inequality. However such a condition is so strict that I'm asking for an improvement.

